# Why does my ice maker intermittently stop and start making ice?

Tags: ice-maker

I have replaced every common issue part. A service agent came and checked it also but the problem continues. It is not the water inlet valve i still get water out the door. The ice maker does not fill, it is not frozen since the fill tube is the new open style. Most times when it stops making ice I can pull out the ice bucket and put it back in, and for some reason it will start again for a while.

I have also noticed the ice bale stays in the middle position. It will not go down to the lowest fill position until it begins functioning again.

I have spoke with a rep from the manufacturer and of course they have no solution. We have done all the usual stuff, jumped the mechanism, replaced the door switch, the harness, verified the wires at the bottom of the door are secure, the ice maker, verified the solenoid is working properly by doing a voltage check and of course I always get a strong stream of water from the water dispenser in the door. The ice cubes I do get are well formed not small or hollow. The harness has voltage, there is voltage to the front of the ice maker behind the square cover. Yet there are times when it just stops making ice and the timer mechanism stops functioning.

It seems to me maybe a short somewhere behind the ice bucket because most often I can remove and replace the bucket and the ice maker begins again, for a while. I also notice when this happens I put my finger in the ice maker and there is no water, and it is not froze up and the bale stays in the middle position, it wont fall to the lowest 'fill' position. I have also tried the clicking the ice bale up and down 3 times quickly to reset the mechanism thing. Nothing happens.

I have purchased the crazy expensive official filters rather than the 3rd party filters and it makes no difference.

Final observation: The water is not filling, the rotation of dispensing ice is not turning, it is not frozen and all the while I get water from the dispenser in door so not the solenoid. Everything else in the fridge works perfectly so I know it is not the main computer panel. And last, why would removing and replacing the ice *bucket* have an effect on the ice maker coming back on?

Comment: There's a lot of information up there, but you haven't even told us what make and model we're talking about.

Comment: Seems more like a rant than a question. Please [edit] this to actually ask a question (take the [tour] to find out more).

Comment: If it's a Samsung or one of the brands made in the same factory (e.g. some GE fridges), a gear inside the icemaker can strip.  No gear replacement, just replacement of the entire icemaker unit.  Here's a teardown video, in 3 parts.  Stripped gear is shown in Part 3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yi-o9HWwnHc

Comment: Whirlpool S/S  Mod WRS321SDHW00.   The ice maker was replaced, twice. 3 days ago it quit again, I pulled the ice bucket out, put it back in and it once again began making and dropping ice. Yesterday it quit making ice yet again, but this time removing and replacing the ice bucket has not resulted in the ice maker producing ice or filling. All the while I am getting water from the door. I hope the helps to clarify. And yes, I guess it is somewhat of a rant. I have spent so much effort and spent so much money with no positive result. Thank you all for any input.